# How can I avoid blocking with Java ServerSocket?

Tags: java, sockets, concurrency, nonblocking

Im working on a socket listener that has to listen on 2 ports for 2 types of data( port 80 and port 81). These data are very similar as in the kind of operations that are performed on the data and are just different because they arrive n different ports. I went ahead and coded an implementation using Java's ServerSocket class, only to realize later that the accept() method of the ServerSocket class is block and my implementation cant afford that. So now i was thinking of implementing the same using Java NIO but after having gone through some tutorials i think i am more confused than how i started. It would be great if someone here could walk me through the whole process, even of it be in pseudo code or jus technical "what to do next"'s.
This is what i plan to achieve.

Listen, like for ever on 2 ports by calling 2 similar threads.(non blocking)
A remote device from some network location connects, sends data and then disconnects.

I think if only knowledge of how NIO can be used to set up a server to listen on a port say port 80, on localhost,is achieved, the rest is all pretty easy to implement.

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NIO is called for when you need to scale to many thousands of simultaneous connections.

Otherwise, I'd suggest using multiple threads. For each port (and its corresponding `ServerSocket`), create a thread that calls `accept()` in a loop. These calls will block, but that is alright because other threads are running, taking care of any available tasks.

When a new `Socket` is accepted, create another thread that is dedicated to that connection. It depends on the application, but typically this thread will read from the socket (a blocking operation), and perform the requested operation, writing the results back to the socket.

This architecture will scale to many hundreds of connections on most desktop platforms. And the programming model is fairly simple, as long as each connection is self-contained and independent of the others (this avoids concurrency issues). Introducing NIO will provide more scalability, but requires a lot of complexity.

Comment: Does not really answer the question: socket listener using NIO

Answer (score 15):

Here a little example to get started with NIO.

It's a server listening on ports 80 and 81 and printing everything that is received on standard output. A connection is closed after receiving a packet starting with `CLOSE`; the whole server is shutdown after receiving a packet starting with `QUIT`. Missing the sending part and error handling could be a bit better. :-)

```
public static void main() throws IOException {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    Selector selector = Selector.open();

    ServerSocketChannel server1 = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    server1.configureBlocking(false);
    server1.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(80));
    server1.register(selector, OP_ACCEPT);

    ServerSocketChannel server2 = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    server2.configureBlocking(false);
    server2.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(81));
    server2.register(selector, OP_ACCEPT);

    while (true) {
        selector.select();
        Iterator<SelectionKey> iter = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            SocketChannel client;
            SelectionKey key = iter.next();
            iter.remove();

            switch (key.readyOps()) {
                case OP_ACCEPT:
                    client = ((ServerSocketChannel) key.channel()).accept();
                    client.configureBlocking(false);
                    client.register(selector, OP_READ);
                    break;
                case OP_READ:
                    client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                    buffer.clear();
                    if (client.read(buffer) != -1) {
                        buffer.flip();
                        String line = new String(buffer.array(), buffer.position(), buffer.remaining());
                        System.out.println(line);
                        if (line.startsWith("CLOSE")) {
                            client.close();
                        } else if (line.startsWith("QUIT")) {
                            for (SelectionKey k : selector.keys()) {
                                k.cancel();
                                k.channel().close();
                            }
                            selector.close();
                            return;
                        }
                    } else {
                        key.cancel();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("unhandled " + key.readyOps());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Obs**: the fields of `SelectionKey` (`OP_ACCEPT`...) are statically imported:

```
import static java.nio.channels.SelectionKey.*;
```

Answer (score 8):

Many frameworks, such as [Apache MINA](http://mina.apache.org/) and [Netty](https://www.jboss.org/netty), have been implemented based on Java NIO to boost non-blocking IO programming. I strongly recommend them to make your NIO programming a joy, rather than a nightmare. They fit your problem.

In addition, try to use an efficient protocol both in transport message size and encode/decode (serialize/deserialize) performance. [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) is a reliable solution in this area. Also take a look at [Kryo](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/) and [KryoNet](http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/). They can be helpful.